# Why does console.log(true, '\t') print true " "?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In Chrome, the following

```
console.log(true, '\t');
```

will print

```
true "  "
```

Why are there quotes hanging around?

(Notice that `console.log(true + '', '\t')` will only print `true`, in the same way that `console.log('a', '\t');` will only print `a`.)

Comment: Not 100% sure, but my guess is because \t is a string expression representing a tab, chrome shows "    " so you can distinguish that it is actually working.

Comment: @asawyer: Doesn't happen for `console.log('a', '\t')` !

Comment: How does console.log('a', '\t'); get represented on the console?

Comment: @RobertH: Edited question. It prints `a`.

Comment: Note: It doesn't matter if you have `"\t"` or `""`. As lobg as it is a string it will print it with quotes after the primitive value `true`.

Comment: i tried `console.log(true,'a\t')` it prints true "a ", but `console.log('a\t',true)` prints a  true(it has something to do with a previous boolean i think

Comment: On Chrome's inspector, tab behaves not as a fixed-width character but a variable-size character that expands up to the next tab stop. Thus, `console.log(true, '\t');` has a short tab, while `console.log(1, '\t');` has a long one.

Comment: just tried `console.log(4,'a')`, prints `4 "a"`, i Think @some is right about primitives

Comment: Just note I tried it too and `console.log('a', '\t');` does have a tab after the 'a'

Comment: @Randomblue As the question was written before your edit, it wasn't clear that you know what `\t` does. If you had tested you would have noticed that `\t` has nothing to do with it. You get similar result with `""`, `" "`, `"\x20"`, "\xa0"` and exactly the same result with `"\x09"` and `"\u0009"`.

Comment: You keep editing the question. With `true + ""` you convert it to a sting, so `console.log(true + '', '\t')` is the same as `console.log(string,string)`. You can test the type if you do `typeof (true + '')`.

Comment: @some: Yes. I don't understand why `console.log` doesn't do the string conversion of each of its arguments. I mean, it must do.

Comment: You really should edit you question and replace `\t` with (for example) `"string"`, because it has nothing to do with the tab character. It is the same for every string. To answer your question one has too look at the source code to see what the different implementations does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically there are two overloads to console.log:

`console.log(formatString, args)` and `console.log(arg1, arg2, ...)`.

More specifically, per [the source code](http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/inspector/front-end/ConsoleMessage.js&exact_package=chromium&q=consolemessage.js&ct=rc&cd=1&sq=), if the first parameter is a string then it treats it as a format string for the other parameters.  Otherwise, each parameter is output directly.

Thus `console.log(true + '', '\t')` outputs 'true' because the first parameter is a string and there is no placeholder for the `\t`, and `console.log(true, '\t')` will output both parameters because `true` is not a string.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to play around with it

```
console.log(true, '\t');
true "  "
```

and then I tried the opposite

```
console.log(false, '\t');
false " "
```

Not sure why but false gives back only one space, while true gives back two o_O... Also if `\t` is in the beginning there is no issue

```
console.log('\t', true);
     true
```

It also doesn't matter what happens after it but it seems that the first parameter if its a boolean in general, will influence all the escaped tabs after with quotes.

```
console.log(false, '\t', '\t');
false " " " "
```

So it definitely has something to do with the first paramater being a boolean because if you try it with strings, it behaves completely normally. I guess its a quirky thing with Google Chrome? I'll need to find the source code to actually see it.

Comment: The 1 vs. 2 spaces issue is possibly because it's a tab and expands to fill up the rest of the tab column.